# How to implement Remote event receiver in sharepoint online?

Tags: sharepoint-online, provider-hosted-app, remote-event-receiver

How to implement Remote event receiver in SharePoint online using provider hosted app and how to configure service bus for debugging remote event receiver in provider hosted app?

Answer (score 4):

If you want to create Remote Event Receiver for List on Host Web, the following articles for your reference:

[Attaching Remote Event Receivers to Lists in the Host Web](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kaevans/2014/02/26/attaching-remote-event-receivers-to-lists-in-the-host-web/)

[Remote Event Receiver (RER) for Host Web using SharePoint Provider Hosted App in Office 365/SharePoint Online Environment](https://blog.kloud.com.au/2014/03/13/remote-event-receiver-rer-for-host-web-using-sharepoint-provider-hosted-app-in-office-365sharepoint-online-environment/)

**OR**

There are two ways to deploy your event receiver, [Check This Link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/cb3097f3-d8a7-46f2-ac29-ca8b50747e7f/how-to-add-remote-event-receiver-on-sharepoint-2013-online-custom-list?forum=sharepointcustomization#dca78fcf-9b51-40ca-a4b9-0d5a2c64b609)

Comment: I am not able to debug remote event receiver on document added in library?